# Poisson process, claims arrival

Tags: poisson-process, expected-value

In some insurance contract the claims arrival process is the Poisson process with $\lambda = 3$. The single claim values are (independent from each other and from arrival process) continuously distributed on $(0,1)$ with density function $f(y)=1$.

The policyholder has the following strategy:

- doesn't report the claim if its value is smaller than $1/3$,
- reports first claim which value is bigger than $1/3$ and then reports all claims regardless of its size.

What is the expected value of not-reported claims in that insurance contract?

I was trying to that in the following way:

Let $K$ be the sum of the value of not-reported claims.
Then $\mathbb{E}K = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(K|N)]$ where $N$ is the number of all claims and we know that $N$~$ Poiss(3)$.
Now I want to determine $\mathbb{E}(K|N=n)$ for each $n$ because then I would be able to finish this task. But I find it hard:

- $\mathbb{E}(K|N=0) = 0$ it's obvious.
- $\mathbb{E}(K|N=1) = ?$
- $\mathbb{E}(K|N=2) = ?$

$\dots$

- $\mathbb{E}(K|N=n) = ?$

I know also that

- $\mathbb{P}($the single claim is reported$) = \frac{2}{3}$ and
- $\mathbb{P}($the single claim is not-reported$) = \frac{1}{3}$
- $ \mathbb{E}($the single claim$)=\frac{1}{2} $

**EDIT***
I want to calculate the expected value of not-reported (equivalently - reported) claims in that insurance contract during **first (one) year**.

Comment: Nice little homework. What is missing is your contribution to the question. You would not take the site for a kind of Yahoo!Answers substitute, by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it should be obvious that the arrival times of the claims are irrelevant; what matters is that they occur.  So the Poisson process is an unnecessary detail.  This is something you have missed; in particular, it is the fact that we are never asked for the number of claims, reported or otherwise, in a fixed period of time, nor are we asked for when the claims occur.  We are interested in the number of unreported claims until the first reported claim.

Once you understand this, the rest is straightforward, since all we are doing is considering independent Bernoulli trials with parameter $p = 2/3$ as the probability of reporting a claim.  Then it follows that the number of unreported claims is a geometric random variable $X$ with $$\Pr[X = x] = (1-p)^x p, \quad x = 0, 1, 2, \ldots.$$  Since unreported claims $Y^* = Y \mid Y < 1/3$ are independent and uniform on $[0, 1/3)$, the expectation is calculated as $$\operatorname{E}[Y^*] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[Y^* \mid X]].$$  This computation is left as an exercise.

Comment: ohhh thanks..! I'm still fixed on the task in which I need to calculate the expected value of REPORTED claims in similar insurance (unfortunately I still can't do that). Back to this task, we have: $\mathbb{E}(Y^*) \mathbb{E}(X) = \frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{18}$. Is that correct?

Comment: of course, I've made a mistake in computing $\mathbb{E}(Y^*)$. It should be $\frac{1}{2}$. And the answer is: $\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{12}$

Comment: @ heropup  Do you know how to handle task in which we have to calucate the expected value of REPORTED claims? Is it just $\mathbb{E}(N-X) \cdot \mathbb{E}(Y)$ where $Y$ is the single claim value?

Comment: The expected value of the size of reported claims is simply $1/2$, because as the question stipulates, the first claim exceeding $1/3$ is reported, then all claims that occur after that are reported regardless of size.  Since you have not restricted the number of claims, the number of non-reported claims is almost surely finite, meaning the number of reported claims is infinite.

Comment: are you sure that it is so simple? I’m not convinced :( We have the number of claims restricted- we set up that the number of claims is Poisson distributed with $\lambda =3$

Comment: I already told you that the Poisson process is irrelevant unless you are asking about claims in a fixed period of time.  The only thing that the Poisson process tells you is that the arrival times of claims follow a particular distribution.  Since you did not ask the question like "what is the expected value of reported claims in $5$ years, if they have an intensity of $\lambda = 3$ claims per year," then the expected claim size will not depend on the distribution of their arrivals.

Comment: The situation is analogous to saying that you repeatedly pick random numbers from a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, and you report the first number that is greater than $1/3$, but after that, you report every number you pick.  What is the expected value of the reported numbers?  The fact that the first number had to be greater than $1/3$ does not impact the average in the limiting case of infinitely many picks.

Comment: OMG! You are genius! I'm so sorry, I've made mistake in formulating the task ... I should write that we look for the expected value of not-reported (or reported) claims from insurance during ONE YEAR. That changes everything... That is why I am so confused. Once again I'm sorry, and thank you for your awarness

Answer (score 0):

Can anyone look at my solution, I'm still not sure of it:

- $\mathbb{E}(K|N=0) =0$
- $\mathbb{E}(K|N=1) = \mathbb{P}($the single claim is not-reported$) \cdot  \mathbb{E}($the single claim which is not reported$) = \frac{1}{3} \cdot  \frac{1}{6}$
- $\mathbb{E}(K|N=2) = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot  \frac{1}{3} \cdot  \frac{1}{6}$

$\dots$

- $\mathbb{E}(K|N=n) = \sum_\limits{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{6} \cdot ( \frac{1}{3} )^k = \frac{1}{12}(1-\frac{1}{3^n} )  $

Now I can calculate the expected value of non-reported claims:

$\mathbb{E}(K)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(K|N=n)) = \mathbb{E}(\frac{1}{12}(1-\frac{1}{3^N} )) = \frac{1}{12}(1-\mathbb{E}(\frac{1}{3^N}) ) = \frac{1}{12}(1-\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{3^n} \cdot \frac{3^n}{n!}e^{-3}) ) = \frac{1}{12}(1-e^{-2} )$